# Microphone capture in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way yet to access microphone in HTML5/ JavaScript?

It is planned for audio streaming, not recording. So nothing with writing to a file etc., but just streaming microphone input.

There is an Audio API and getUserMedia(). At the moment, getting audio doesn't seem possible. Is there a way or a workaround?

Comment: No, it is only allowed to use HTML5, Javascript and C#, possibly ASP.NET. It does not seem to be possible to realize and audio chat with this languages without using desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you add "x-webkit-speech" to your input field I believe all web kit browsers will add the HTML5 audio icon which enables audio input.

```
<input type="text" name="query" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search the Site" tabindex="1" x-webkit-speech>
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, I will try it. It is about streaming live audio. So what you mean is, if I use x-webkit-speech, other audio input features will start working? I'll write again after  giving it a try.

Comment: So a little information update. x-webkit-speech oviously seems to have done something. Since it was in the code (even after taking it out again), an <audio>-element can be seen as playing, i.e. it looks like it was playing a stream, with visible controls and a time that shows. Strange is: You don't hear any kind of sound. So has anyone ever seen this problem?